# Dynamic transform style property while scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm in a blind spot with my small jQuery script.
The point is that I'm trying to make an element to rotate, and to apply the rotation value dynamically as the user is scrolling through the page.

It works here on stackoverflow but I can't get this to work on my website...
The only external library I'm using is JQuery.

Can you please tell me where is the problem?

```js
var $animObject = $('.animateObject');
var $window = $(window);

$window.on('scroll', function() {
  var fromTop = $window.scrollTop() / -4;
  $animObject.css('transform', 'rotate(' + fromTop + 'deg)')
});
```

```css
.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url('https://simply-design.ml/dev/img/start1.jpg');
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.header-content {
  padding: 30px;
  max-width: 470px;
}

.header-wrapper {
  padding: 50px;
  border: solid 3px #fff;
}

.header h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.header p {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.p-title {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
}

.head-button {
  padding: 10px 25px;
  background-color: #3b88df;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}

.head-button:hover {
  background-color: #2c78ce;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<header class="header">
  <div class="header-content">
    <center>
      <div class="header-wrapper animateObject">
        <h1>title</h1>
        <div style="height: 2px; width: 70px; background-color: #fff; margin: 20px;"></div>
        <p>subtitle</p>
      </div>
    </center>
  </div>
</header>

<div style="height: 1000px"></div>
```

Comment: If something works in a snippet but not on your site there must be a configuration error somewhere. Check the console for errors

Comment: it's probably because the element you are trying to rotate isn't at the top of the page, so by the time you are scrolling to it, it has already been rotated off-screen. you should wait until the window has scrolled to the element, and then start from there with a delta.

Comment: We can't find the error if there's none in the snippet and we can't see what's different in your website. It could be same variable name that overwrites, different CSS rules, many things..

Comment: I checked the console for any bugs or errorr, I tried around 3 or 4 configurations and I didn't find anything...

Comment: refer the jquery library as  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check this example I've made without *jQuery*, which shows how to rotate an element based on the scroll position of the window, but *only* once the element is **in view**.

I've decided to do this without *jQuery* because it's better for performance, working directly with the DOM instead of passing through *jQuery*, and also because it's relatively simple code, understandable.

1. Find out how much was scrolled
2. Get the target's element absolute position
3. Calculate if the element is within the viewport (if not, break)
4. If it's in, save the scroll value at that point
5. Subtract that value from the current scroll value to get the value from that point on
6. Use the new value as baseline for the transformation

```js
var elm = document.querySelector('b');

var onScroll = (function(){
  var startPos;
  
  function run(){
    var fromTop = window.pageYOffset, 
        rect = elm.getBoundingClientRect(),
        scrollDelta;

    // check if element is in viewport
    if( (rect.top - window.innerHeight) <= 0 && rect.bottom > 0 )
       startPos = startPos === undefined ? fromTop : startPos;
    else{
      startPos = 0;
      return;
    }
    
    scrollDelta = (fromTop - startPos) * 1; // "speed" per scrolled frame
    elm.style.transform = `translateX(${scrollDelta}px) rotate(${scrollDelta}deg)`;
    
    console.clear();
    console.log(scrollDelta);
  }
  
  run();
  
  return run;
})()

window.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
```

```css
html, body{ height:100%; }
body{ height:1500px; }

b{ 
  position:fixed;
  top: 20px;
  left:20px;

  width:100px;
  height:100px;

  background:red;
}
```

```html
<b></b>
```

inspect the `<b>` element while scrolling and see that it only gets transform when it is in view.