# Scroll Event Catch with jquery or vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i catch scroll event? For example 1024px scroll down to top notify appears. 
I'm stuck at this code;

```
(function () {
    var previousScroll = 0;

    $(window).scroll(function(){
    var currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (currentScroll > previousScroll){
            notify appears
        } else {
            notify appears
        }
     previousScroll = currentScroll;
      });
}());
```

Comment: See my answer here to a very similar question - https://stackoverflow.com/a/51044763/104380

Comment: Thank you i will checkout. Actually I try to find to solitions for this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50561645/upscroll-with-pushstate-organization

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  if ( scrollTop > 1024 ) { 
    //your code block
  }
});
```

the scrollTop() method sets or returns the vertical scrollbar position for the selected elements.